Auto executing file
Hi is there any way to make a file auto executing in android and windows. I'm learning to be an ethical hacker. Even though the question seems evil, I'm using that to gain knowledge about  ways to prevent such things happening.
I'm a beginner and I'm trying to learn

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
